# Racket macro function with same name as basic functions

Tags: macros, racket

Is it possible to define a macro that has same name as a function in racket, but not override it. (So that name would have 2 possible usage, depending on the passed argument)

For example function *round*.

***1. usage (racket function)***

```
( round 1.2 )
-> 1
```

***2. usage (our macro)***

```
(round (someStruct arg)) 
-> resultStruct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using function

```
(require (only-in racket [round @round]))
(define (my-round v)
  ;; do whatever you want to do here
  "hello")

(define (round v)
  (cond
    [(number? v) (@round v)]
    [else (my-round v)]))

(define x 1.2)
(round x) ;=> 1.0
(define y "abc")
(round y) ;=> "hello"
```

By defining `round` as a function, the case analysis is done on the *value* that is passed into the function at *runtime*.

### Using macro

```
(require syntax/parse/define 
         (only-in racket [round @round]))

(define-syntax-parser round
  [(_ x:number) #'(@round x)]
  [(_ x) #'"hello"])

(define x 1.2)
(round x) ;=> "hello"
(define y "abc")
(round y) ;=> "hello"
(round 1.2) ;=> 1.0
(round (this is not a sensible expression but it works (()))) ;=> "hello"
```

By defining `round` as a macro, the case analysis is done on the *syntax fragment* that is passed into the macro at *compile-time*. In the above example, we will use the actual Racket's `round` when the operand of the macro is a literal number. Everything else will be transformed to `"hello"`. Note that at compile-time, identifiers like `x` is not evaluated and associated to a value yet. The only thing you know is that it is an identifier, which is not a literal number, so it transforms to `"hello"`. This program after macro expansion will roughly be:

```
(require syntax/parse/define 
         (only-in racket [round @round]))

(define x 1.2)
"hello"
(define y "abc")
"hello"
(@round 1.2)
"hello"
```

Choose which one you prefer. I suspect that you actually want to use function rather than macro.

Comment: That's it! Thank you <3